# Google Play Console API

Tags: google-play-console

Issue: My clients need to access app information, such as **installs**, **uninstalls**, and **respond app user comments**.
They access the **Google Play Console** to manage the information above, but are computer laymen, and with access to the **Google Play Console** they can run undesirable settings or even remove the app from the **Google Play Console**.

Solution: Create a **web portal** for them to view **only specific information** (**Installations**, **Uninstallations** and **responding to end user comments from the app**).

Doubt: What **API** will the portal that I'm going to develop need to consume to display the information (**Installs**, **Uninstallations** and **answer End User Comments**)?

Annex draft of the project.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know much about the Google Play Console, but i'll try to help anyway. Are users confused because signing in require too much information ? How is login managed for now ?

Comment: I made a heatmap that downloads csv from google play but they only update like every couple days. As of today they are only updated to august 8th. I never heard of any google play console apis though

Comment: https://github.com/copypasteearth/GooglePlayDeveloperMap  it is a java application links in the readme are how to get the csv's. Just recently the total downloads stopped working. I think there is a way to get the csv through web requests

Comment: I don't know any Google Play Console APIs neither, and there's none listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/). I may be wrong but the Google Play Console is for developers right ? Why would end-users login to it ?

Comment: Actually theyre updated to august 11th as of today i just looked

Comment: @Hollyol **edited** the request and added image for a better understanding of the project. I hope you're clearer for success with my portal.

Comment: @JRowan **edited** the request and added image for a better understanding of the project. I hope you're clearer for success with my portal.

Comment: @Ever So what you want is to limit the end-user to : 1 - See how many times your app where installed / unistalled, 2 - Allow them to comment, and react to any other end-user's comment. Am i right ?

Comment: @Hollyol Correct, the portal will be the "intermediary" of the Google Play Console. In this way, access to access is limited as a Google feature.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [user permissions in the Play console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691) to prevent them from doing anything undesirable? You can give users read only access, and even per-app access.

Then you don't have to write any code at all.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, your portal will mainly need two things :

- The reviews sent by users via Google Play Store
- The Google Play Console reports

Then, you will have to do the job yourself, **create some kind of blog where end-users can posts reviews, and other users can comment it**. You will also need to **retrieve the reviews posted via Google Play Store, and use this data to automatically post a new review on your portal**. The [Reply to Reviews API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews) can help you to retrieve such reviews, in a formated output (Json).

The install and uninstall are available thanks to Google Play Console reports, stored in a private Google Cloud Storage bucket. There are a few [ways to download these reports](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en&ref_topic=7071935), but i guess you want **get them programmatically in order to automate the process**. You will need [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to achieve this task. I understood gsutil gives you CSV files, witch can be parsed pretty easily, in order to isolate ans send the informations you need to your portal.